# Joomla - Warning! Failed to move file error

Tags: permissions, joomla, module

I have found some solutions to this error and tried implementing them but none of which has worked and hope that some here at SO might have a different answer.

I get this error, "Warning! Failed to move file" when I try install modules into my new installation of Joomla here:

http://sun-eng.sixfoot.co.za

Here's some solutions I have tried to no avail:

http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?f=199&t=223206

http://www.saibharadwaj.com/blog/2008/03/warning-failed-to-move-file-joomla-10x-joomla-15x/

Anyone know of another solution to this please?

Thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Go to Help -> System Info in your administrator backend and check your Directory Permissions tab to make sure everything is writable.

Also make sure your Path to Temp Folder is correct in Site -> Global Configuration.

Finally, check to make sure that the module isn't already installed.  It's possible that some files already got copied or something and now your system is having problems overwriting them.

If none of this works, let us know if the error message specifies which file can't be moved.  That would help figure out a solution.

Comment: Hi Will.  I've followed your solution, path is good, permissions are now good, but I receive the same error, preceded by "Error! Could not find an XML setup file in the package.".  Any ideas?

Comment: I found another solution.  Adding the following to my .htaccess file solved it: php_value upload_max_filesize 10M

Comment: For `joomla-3.3.4` it's in `System > System Information > Folder Permissions`.

Answer (score 2):

In the configuration folder change the temporal folder location to `/tmp` (`public $tmp_path = '/tmp';`) or create your own temperate folder and set it to `/myowntemp` and change the file permission to `777`. you are good to go .

Comment: Will setting permission to 777 won't cause security risks?

Answer (score 1):

This is typically a file permissions issue.  If the system cannot write to the tmp directory within Joomla it will give you the "Warning Failed To Move File" error.

The typical solution is to make the directory wide-open, in general a bad practice but a quick fix.   You log in to the Linux command line via a terminal (telnet or ssh) session and set the permissions of the directory.

```
# chmod -R 777 ./tmp
```

The better option is to find out what user/group the Apache server is running as and assign the permissions accordingly.  For example, if Apache is running your site as the myuser:nobody user:group then you can open up write permissions for the group by changing ownership of the tmp folder and making it writable by anyone in the group:

```
# chgrp -R nobody ./tmp
# chmod -R 775 ./tmp
```

Security can be a pain to get set correctly if you don't know *nix commands and security settings, so most people just blast a huge hole in the security with chmod 777.

The next thing you'll probably run into is another error message about not being able to update a specific directory.  Again, this is a permissions issue and is typically a piece of the file being unzipped into the administrator subdirectory.  Depending on whether your installing a component, a module, or a complex plugin with multiple pieces you may need to open up one or more of these directories using the same approach as above.  Here is the "blow a big open hole in security" method:

```
# chmod -R 777 ./administrator/
```

Or more selectively:

```
# chmod -R 777 ./administrator/components/
# chmod -R 777 ./administrator/modules/
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are a linux user then it is very simple to solve. Just type the following command and try again to install plugin/entension.

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/my_joomla_folder
```

You can also refer [this](https://www.rsjoomla.com/support/view-article/1012-troubleshooting-extension-installation-errors.html) link for brief information regarding permission of each folder and file.
Cheers!!

Answer (score 1):

In Joomla 3.x you should go to System->System Information to see directory permissions [image]

[image]

If one or more directories that are listed are not "writable" then you should change the permission of those directories: 
If you are using one of Linux distributions you can use this command
to give the directories read/write/execute permission:

sudo chmod 777 -R address_of_lampp_directory/lampp/htdocs/joomla_directory

Answer (score 0):

I have had a similar issue today and found is was the permissions set on the 'temp folder'. To resolve I changed them to 777 and my plugin installs worked fine!!

Answer (score 0):

Another thing to check is whether you actually have space on the disk. I had this error and discovered that the drive was 100% full. Removing some unused files fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

One other thing to try if everything else is not working is to add the following to your .htaccess file:

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 10M
```

Make sure 10M covers the size of the file you are uploading - increase it if your file is 12Mb, for instance.

[[Source]](http://www.joomlarulez.com/faq/44-faq/81-troobleshooting-qerror-could-not-find-a-joomla-xml-setup-file-in-the-packageq.html)

Answer (score 0):

This issue was solved like this.
On the configuration.php file change the tmp_path variable according to:

if you site is mysite.azurewebsites.net, the path should looks like
'C:\DWASFiles\Sites\mysite\VirtualDirectory0\site\wwwroot\tmp'
instead of
'C:\DWASFiles\Sites\mysite.azurewebsites.net\VirtualDirectory0\site\wwwroot\tmp'

Refer to the link: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsazurewebsitespreview/thread/2701eadc-9977-46ab-9c56-81a2234bdce4

Answer (score 0):

I did it and every is working for every error problem with OSX, I use OSX version 10.9.2 and get many problems. The way to fix every error is

```
# cd /Applications
# chmod -R 777 ./XAMPP
```

some files might not change permission but the problem is gone.
you can create folder and upload fine and picture, including install plugin.